# UIImagePickerController dismiss animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

[image: Storyboard]

When I try to present a UIImageViewController from the table view, the starting animation is a vertical cover, which I want, but when the controller gets dismissed, the animation is a Horizontal Flip. I tried `[self presentViewController:self.imageController animated:YES completion:nil];` and `[self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imageController animated:YES completion:nil];` but the dismiss animation is the same in both cases. When I remove the middle view controller (i.e just navigation controller with the tableview as its root), the dismiss animation is correct (cover vertical).

Anyone know how I can get the correct dismiss animation with the current storyboard configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.imageController animated:YES];
```

Comment: If you do that, this happens: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'